# node.js code does not read else condition when user does not specify a search argument (only reads if condition)

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

Currently, my if/else statement does not work correctly as it never goes to the else portion of my code. The node app takes in an argument (process.argv[3]) and uses that to pick the API to call. process.argv[4] is used to specify what to search (example "Yesterday") and works correctly if argument is provided.  However, I want to have a default search if user leaves that argument blank. I'm unsure of why it never goes to the else portion of the code.

I'm new to programming so I'm sure this is stupid error on my part, but I've tried rewritting the statement and same issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getSpotifySongInfo() {
        //4th node argument is reserved for the song user wants to select
        var query = process.argv[3];
        if (query !== "") {
            //could make this less repeating code by passing the song as a parameter?
            spotifyClient.search({ type: 'track', query: query, limit: 1 }, function (err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log("=============Artist==Track==Album==PreviewURL=============================");
                    console.log("Artist: " + data.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name);
                    console.log("Track: " + data.tracks.items[0].name);
                    console.log("Album: " + data.tracks.items[0].name);
                    console.log("Preview URL: " + data.tracks.items[0].preview_url);
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });

        } else {
            //need to make this specific for Ace of Base. For some reason it's not changing the query to reflect default song. I've tried commenting this portion out and just testing w/ a simple console.log("test") and nothing...
            query = 'The Sign';
            spotifyClient.search({ type: 'track', query: query, limit: 1 }, function (err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log("=============Artist==Track==Album==PreviewURL=============================");
                    console.log("Artist: " + data.tracks.items[0].artists[0].name);
                    console.log("Track: " + data.tracks.items[0].name);
                    console.log("Album: " + data.tracks.items[0].name);
                    console.log("Preview URL: " + data.tracks.items[0].preview_url);
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well...at the moment, the initializer is commented out, so `query === undefined`

Comment: Good catch. I commented that portion out when formatting the question to ask.  My actual code does not have it commented out. Thanks.

Comment: Initialize `query` like so: `query = process.argv[3] || 'The Sign';` This will assign the value of `process.argv[3]` if it has a value, or if it has not a value, a default string is assigned. That way you can omit the `if .. else` construction. Currently the described behavior is possible only, when `query` has some other value than the empty string. Notice, that `undefined` is also a value. Have you checked the value of that variable?

Comment: @Teemu thank you that worked and is a very neat way to clean things up.  The undefined value is why I was getting nothing.  Thank you very much! That was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (query !== "")` is a bad test and probably doesn't do what you want. For example:

```
var query = undefined;
query !== ""
// true

query = null
query !== ""
// true
```

You are testing for a very specific thing — an empty string — which you probably aren't getting as an argument to your function.

A better way that leads to a lot less code is to assign a value to `query` if none exists. You can do some thing like:

```
if (!query) {
   query = 'The Sign'
}
```

Then you don't need the `if/else` code at all.  A quick and easy way to do this is:

```
 var query = process.argv[3] || 'The Sign'
```

This will either assign the value of `process.argv[3]` or, if that value is falsy, you'll get the default. This is a very common pattern in Javascript.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation.  That makes sense now that you explained it, my understanding of JavaScript obviously isn't complete.  Thanks for your help and teaching me something.